# asp.net Table borders

Tags: c#, asp.net, border

I need to add Right borders to each of my asp:table columns (I have 3 going across).
The following code is for the table but it only places borders around the whole table:

```
style="border-left: 3px solid blue; border-right: 3px solid blue"
```

How to add it to columns and also define a custom colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pOcHa got it for all tables  with a class assigned .

To define styles for specific named tables you would use the ID Selector:

```
/* Just named tables */
#Table1 td{ border-right:2px solid #00F;}
```

CSS file:

```
/* All tables */
table td{ border-right:2px solid #00F;}

/* All tables with Rightborders class */
table.Rightborders td{ border-right:2px solid #00F;}

/* Just named tables */
#Table1 td{ border-right:2px solid #00F;}
```

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" CssClass="Rightborders" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>1</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>2</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>3</asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

-J

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: Not all tables, just the ones with a `RightBorders` class (lookup css selectors), edit it to avoid confusing people.

Comment: True. Updated for all tables vs those with the class assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `RightBorders` css class to your table, and define it like this:

```
table.RightBorders td { border-right: 1px solid "custom color" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tablecell
    {
        border-right:3px solid #bbb;
    }
</style>


<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tablecell">c1</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tablecell">c2</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tablecell">c1</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tablecell">c2</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: this way you can avoid last columns border if you want by removing the `CssClass` in that cell